# Occurence matrix associated to a single-string grammar of a string.

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

Define $n_A(G) = $ number of occurences of symbol $A$ in the grammar $G$ (RHS's of rules).

Then a smallest grammar minimizes $|G| = \sum_{A \in \Sigma} n_A(G)$ where $\Sigma$ is the alphabet of $G$ (all symbols occuring).  Let $n_A(B) = 0$ if $A$ doesn't occur in $B$ and $n_A(B) = $ the number of times $A$ occurs in any rule with LHS $A$.  Clearly $|G|$ is also $|G| = \sum_{A,B \in \Sigma} n_A(B)$.

Then every grammar has an associated square matrix $M$, where row and column indexes correspond to letters in $\Sigma$:

Ex. $G = \{S \to AABaa, A \to BBBa, B \to aaa\} \implies M = $
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\ & S & A & B & a \\
S & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
A & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
B & 1 & 3 & 0 & 0 \\
a & 2 & 1 & 3 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the sum of the entries in $M$ is equal to $|G|$, and each entry is $n_{\text{row}}(\text{column})$.

Can grammar operations then be written as matrix operations?  Be creative...

For instance, the operation $\exp(A)$ (expand all occurences of variable $A$) is:

$S_c := S_c + 2A_c$ where $c, r$ will indicate column or row.  $G$ in the example is not a smallest grammar of $s = a^{25}$, but $G'= \{S \to AAAAA, B \to aaaaa\}$ is.  Can we transform $M$ into:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

using row and column operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add $-1$'s allong the diagonal of $M = (m_{i,j})$ used for subtracting $k$ below:

The grammar-constrained operations would be:

$$
C_j := C_j + k \cdot C_i , \\ k \leq m_{i,j}\\
m_{i,j} := m_{i,j} + k \\
\equiv \text{expanding variable } i \text{ inside } j
$$

We can accomplish this by multiplying $M$ on the right by an identity matrix with a $k$ at $m_{j,i}$ :

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
k & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Thus expansion of $k$ $A's$ inside $S$ can be done with an invertible elementary  column matrix.  But when $m_{i,j}$ drops to zero for all $j$ we do not sum in (non-diagonal) column $i$ entries and we can delete that colum/row (symbol $i$).  Alternatively, strictly constrain $k \lt m_{i,j}$ and work only with grammars on a fixed $n$ variables at any one time.